# Is there a way to see the html elements events and their code in Chrome like in Firefox?

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, dom-events, developer-tools

While debugging, sometimes I get stuck finding the correct event, but recently I found out that Firefox indicates you all the events of an element and their code, I wonder if there is something similar in Chrome. I know that maybe Developer

Tools would have something like that, but I don't understand this a lot, and with Firefox I have all the events very fast.

Here are a few pics of what I mean. I cannot upload images because my account is new.

```
https://ibb.co/5W2M3TT
https://ibb.co/4T8rWc1
https://ibb.co/4YWzRv3
https://ibb.co/LQVxst1
```

Comment: It's pretty much the same thing in Chrome's developer tools. I'm not clear about what is not understood?

Comment: Have you checked the images in the urls? I mean if there is something like the button "event" that appears in Firefox and when I click it i can see all the events an the exact event code. Is there something like that in Chrome's developer tools? Because I can't find where it is.

Comment: I now see what you mean with the small `[event]` button. It appears that Chrome does not (yet) have that feature, so one has to 'dig' into the sources to find the related event(s). I also primarily use Firefox to develop, and then load Chrome to compare the UI and other handling, so I had not noticed that difference in the web inspector. Another nifty feature to know that Firefox has, that Chrome does not, is in the view page source. If you see some bolded red text areas, you can hover, and a tip text appears with trouble at that point. (tags out of place, no space between attributes, etc)